# Actual millis in a C++

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

Is it possible to get the actual millis since I-don't-know in a C++-programm like `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java? I know `time()`, but I think it's not exactly enough to measure short times, is it?

Comment: Take a look at these questions: [how to get time in millis in c++ just like java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831841/how-to-get-time-in-millis-in-c-just-like-java) and [C++ Timer function to provide time in nano seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds)

Comment: @slugonamission: that is *nix specific...

Comment: @LaszloPapp - oops, deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the language standard these days (some years now):

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac0a4da363090849)**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto epoch = high_resolution_clock::from_time_t(0);
    // ...
    auto now   = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto mseconds = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now - epoch).count();

    std::cout << "millis: " << mseconds;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is how I would do it in C++. Note: `using namespace std::chrono;` seems very worth it here.

Comment: Changed the sample to actually print milliseconds since the epoch

Comment: Although [even MSVC, the compiler-that-always-lags-behing, had `<chrono>` in VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @LaszloPapp *This will not work without C++11 support* -- there no point to consider outdated standards, unless you're dealing with legacy code.

Comment: @Walter: clearly, you have not worked much with embedded. I understand bleeding edge desktop people hardly see out of their box, but that is just a specific domain. To be fair, even on desktop there are plenty of VS2010 and VS2008 users, not to mention Windows CE, etc.

Comment: Okay,  time to calm down people.  It's all useful information. No need to imply incompetence left or right

Comment: @LaszloPapp: And let's not forget corporate world, the migration from gcc 3.4 to gcc 4.3 is still ongoing where I work (has been for the last 7 years)...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: yes, I agree.

Comment: should the code say 
auto epoch = system_clock::from_time_t(0);
? My code wouldn't compile with high_resolution_clock::from_time_t(0);

Comment: @Tad your compiler might not be to update/have full support for std::chrono (yet): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock. Depending on the resolution you desire, `system_clock` could be fine for your purposes

Comment: I used this code and time calculated was   1412002099144 miliseconds. Is time 0 in 1970? Why not use system_clock::now()? I am using gcc 4.9

Comment: @Tad look at the question for context. Heck, here's a link for you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you also have `clock()`

```
#include <time.h>

...

clock_t start = clock();
... some processing ...
clock_t stop = clock();

double elapsed = double(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

There are also other more accurate ways of measure timings, but they are more dependent on which king of system you're running your programs on.

Comment: Ok, is there any constant to get milliseconds?

Comment: The `clock` function returns CPU time. I get the impression this is asking about wall time.

Comment: @pear: what about multiplying the result of the division by 1000? :-)

Comment: @6502: Of course, but this would not improve the accuracy, would it?

Comment: @PEAR: the value of the constant `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is system dependent and the same goes for the provided accuracy (they are not required to be aligned; e.g. `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` could be 100000 but the accuracy just 20ms).

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++11 support available, you may want to look into `std::chrono`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

long fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n < 3) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "f(42) = " << fibonacci(42) << '\n';
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
              << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

Failing that, you could use the C style std::time as follows:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(NULL);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
}
```

Comment: What do seconds sinds the epoch have to do with things?

Comment: @sehe: read about System.currentTimeMillis in the original question, please. This may be [a good starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271039/does-system-currenttimemillis-return-utc-time).